# Add value into three different variables from Foreach-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a file (config.cfg) which has three strings like this: `host:user:pass`

In my Unix code, I do this to get and assign the value into three different variables:

```
  $FTP_HOST=$( cut -f1 -d: config.cfg )
  $FTP_USER=$( cut -f2 -d: config.cfg )
  $FTP_PASS=$( cut -f3 -d: config.cfg )
```

How can I do this in PowerShell 3.0? I have tried with Foreach-Object but couldn't find a way to assign into three variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell learned from Perl and Python, so you can do this:

```psh
$FTP_HOST, $FTP_USER, $FTP_PASS = (Get-Content .\config.cfg) -split ':'
```

Comment: Great! I do prefer single-line stuff. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the data by colon and assign each element:

```
$config = Get-Content config.cfg
$FTP_HOST = ($config -split ":")[0]
$FTP_USER = ($config -split ":")[1]
$FTP_PASS = ($config -split ":")[2]
```

Or pre-split the data into an array and then assign the array elements:

```
$config = Get-Content config.cfg
$carry = $config -split ":"
$FTP_HOST = $carry[0]
#etc...
```

Comment: Works nice and smooth. Thank you!